# Discord bot in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that sends a random image of goat (which are in a folder) when a user types !goat. But I can't get there and can't really find cases like mine.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
import random
import os

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!goat'):

            with open(random.choice(os.listdir("/home/leo/Bureau/bot-discord/image")), 'rb') as f:
                picture = discord.File(f)
                await channel.send(channel, picture)
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `listdir` returns the name of the files, not the complete paths.

Comment: Oh ok it's a problem lol. Do you have any method I can use ?

Comment: @LéoCarrez why not just store the path in a variable, then concatenate the path and the file name?

Comment: Have a look at [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob). I think that is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Because my code works, he takes a random image in my folder but he don't send the picture on discord he return an error like : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'the Name Of The Picture'.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can solve your problem using [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
import glob
from pprint import pprint
from random import choice

goats = glob.glob("P:/Goats/*.png")
pprint(goats)
print(choice(goats), "is the chosen one!")
```

Output:

```
['P:/Goats\\Goat0.png',
 'P:/Goats\\Goat1.png',
 'P:/Goats\\Goat2.png',
 'P:/Goats\\Goat3.png',
 'P:/Goats\\Goat4.png',
 'P:/Goats\\Goat5.png',
 'P:/Goats\\Goat6.png',
 'P:/Goats\\Goat7.png',
 'P:/Goats\\Goat8.png',
 'P:/Goats\\Goat9.png']
P:/Goats\Goat2.png is the chosen one!
```

Comment: Thanks your code is worked but i don't know how i can send the picture on channel discord

Comment: Use `discord.File`: `channel.send(file=discord.File(fp="path/to/file.png", filename="image.png"))`.

Comment: @LéoCarrez You have to target the channel that the message was sent from. I'm not 100%, but you should be able to access the channel-object via `message.channel` in your original code.

Comment: Do you know how can I do that because i've try to found it on discord.py doc but i don't understand how it's works.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the answer on several forum and doc. So my code is :

```
import discord
import glob
from pprint import pprint
from random import choice

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!goat'):

            goat = glob.glob("/home/leo/Bureau/bot-discord/image/*.jpeg")
            pprint(goat)
            image = choice(goat)

            await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(image))
```

thanks everyone for your answers. Have a good day.